# How to get Number input on screen javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css

Im trying to get my numbers to display the assigned value on screen but I have no clue how to do it.

```
<div class="container">
      <div class="Calaculatorout">
        <div class="calculatordisplay">0</div>
        <div class="buttons">
          <button class="nine">9</button>
          <button class="eight">8</button>
          <button class="seven">7</button>
          <button class="six">6</button>
          <button class="five">5</button>
          <button class="four">4</button>
          <button class="three">3</button>
          <button class="two">2</button>
          <button class="one">1</button>
          <button class="zero">0</button>
          <button class="multi">X</button>
          <button class="divide">/</button>
          <button class="plus">+</button>
          <button class="minus">-</button>
          <button class="myForm">AC</button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

I need to find a way to assign the values in js or for them to appear on the webpage.

```
const del = document.querySelector(".back");
const buttons = document.querySelectorAll(".buttons");

const clear = document.querySelector(".clear");
const display = document.querySelector(".calculatordisplay");

buttons.forEach((button) => {
  buttons.addEventListener("click", (e) => {
    appendNumber(e);
    updateDisplay();
  });
});

function updateDisplay() {
  display.textcontent;
}
```

Comment: Please post the definition of `appendNumber`.

Comment: You need to assign to `display.textContent` (note the capital `C`).

Answer (score 0):

Please be more specific with the question and provide all the details.

Anyway, the below code will help you to display the button value on the screen. Also, I added the concatenation logic.

But if you are trying to implement a calculator you need to do an extra bit of logic. Don't forget to handle `number/0` or `0/0` scenario

```js
var disp = '';
function myFunction(x) {
    disp = disp + x;
    if(x == "AC") {
        document.getElementById("calculatordisplay").innerHTML = 0;
    } else if(disp == "") {
        document.getElementById("calculatordisplay").innerHTML = x;
    } else {
        document.getElementById("calculatordisplay").innerHTML = disp;
    }
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="Calaculatorout">
    <div id="calculatordisplay">0</div>
    <div id="buttons">
      <button onclick="myFunction(value)" id="nine" value="9">9</button>
      <button onclick="myFunction(value)" id="eight" value="8">8</button>
      <button onclick="myFunction(value)" id="seven" value="7">7</button>
      <button onclick="myFunction(value)" id="six" value="6">6</button>
      <button onclick="myFunction(value)" id="five" value="5">5</button>
      <button onclick="myFunction(value)" id="four" value="4">4</button>
      <button onclick="myFunction(value)" id="three" value="3">3</button>
      <button onclick="myFunction(value)" id="two" value="2">2</button>
      <button onclick="myFunction(value)" id="one" value="1">1</button>
      <button onclick="myFunction(value)" id="zero" value="0">0</button>
      <button onclick="myFunction(value)" id="multi" value="X">X</button>
      <button onclick="myFunction(value)" id="divide" value="/">/</button>
      <button onclick="myFunction(value)" id="plus" value="+">+</button>
      <button onclick="myFunction(value)" id="minus" value="-">-</button>
      <button onclick="myFunction(value)" id="myForm" value="AC">AC</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```